# MVVM Should I put the network fetching in ViewModel or View?

Tags: swift, uitableview, networking, mvvm, request

I'm trying to learn MVVM, its all new to me, but I get the general gist of it. But one thing that bothers me is where I should fetch the network call for my model type. I read some articles here and there, both giving different answers of course, and for now I've placed it inside the view, to be called in viewDidLoad().

It seems off though because view should only hold UI related stuff and was thinking of putting it in the view-model and calling the fetch function from there.

Of course, I am aware that people have different preference as to where this should go as seeing the debate online. But still.. I want to write code that makes sense.

If I am completely off with what I am talking about, and it depends on the situation, then enlighten me please.

Below is my sample weather project fetching a request for daily weathers.

```
class WeatherListViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

    private var request: AnyObject?
    private var weatherListViewModel = WeatherListViewModel()
    private let sessionProvider = URLSessionProvider()

    private let cellId = "cell"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        fetchDailyWeather()
        setupTableViewDataSource()
    }

    private func setupTableViewDataSource() {
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellId)
    }

    // TODO: - Put this networking request in viewModel???
    private func fetchDailyWeather() {
        sessionProvider.request(type: WeatherWrapper.self, service: WeatherService.daily) { [weak self] result in
            switch result {
            case let .success(weatherWrapper):
                let weathers = weatherWrapper.daily.weathers
                for weather in weathers {
                    self?.weatherListViewModel.addWeather(weather)

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self?.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
                }

            case let .failure(error):
                print("ERROR: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
}


// This is of course in a different file. For now it's a struct, but will change to class when appropriate.

struct WeatherListViewModel {

    private(set) var weathers = [Weather]()

//    var date: Date {
//        return
//    }

    mutating func addWeather(_ weatherModel: Weather) {
        weathers.append(weatherModel)
    }

    func numberOfRows(inSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return weathers.count
    }

    func modelAt(_ index: Int) -> Weather {
        return weathers[index]
    }
}
```